# How to disable django cms top edit bar on front pages in django

Tags: django, django-cms

By mistake I have installed django-cms; now on top of every page I see the django cms bar for adding or editing pages.

It loads unnecessary javascript files which conflict with my own scripts.

How can I remove django-cms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how you accidentally install something, but check your source tree and `INSTALLED_APPS` (in `settings.py`) and remove any trace of `django-cms`.

Comment: thanks for that , i did that. but is there any way to just disable the top bar only so that it don't load its js libraries

Answer (score 17):

This has become optional since the 2.2+ release of django-cms. Templates now require `{% cms_toolbar %}` for the toolbar to appear.

Answer (score 2):

The js for the front end editing is only visible when you are logged in, if you were worried about it causing an overhead for other users. I haven't tried it, but it might also respect the users permissions (i.e. if you don't give a user permission to edit cms pages it may not show).